# How to work with plugin aws-native, on Pulumi, with Python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to use aws-native on a project that is already using aws. I have installed the new plugin, but when I try "pulumi up", I get:

```
default_4_33_0 (pulumi:providers:aws-native)
error: no resource plugin 'aws-native-v4.33.0' found in the workspace or on your $PATH, install the plugin using `pulumi plugin install resource aws-native v4.33.0`
```

v4.33.0 is the version for the classic aws plugin. It looks like the versions are getting mixed up. If I list the installed plugins, I get:

```
$ pulumi plugin ls
NAME        KIND      VERSION  SIZE    INSTALLED  LAST USED
aws         resource  4.33.0   356 MB  n/a        5 minutes ago
aws         resource  4.19.0   279 MB  n/a        5 minutes ago
aws-native  resource  0.9.0    64 MB   n/a        5 minutes ago
github      resource  4.8.1    44 MB   n/a        5 minutes ago
random      resource  4.3.1    32 MB   n/a        5 minutes ago
```

How to fix this situation, so that I can use aws and aws-nativ side-by-side, with Python?

Update 1:

To install aws-plugin, I have included "aws-native" on my requirements file, then ran `venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt`. Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
pulumi>=3.0.0,<4.0.0
pulumi-aws>=4.0.0,<5.0.0
pulumi-aws-native
pulumi-github
pulumi-random
pytest
requests
```

Update 2:

I'm already using aws classic resources. With aws-native, I'm trying to use SlackChannelConfiguration:

```py
from pulumi_aws_native.chatbot import SlackChannelConfiguration
```

Trying to create the following resource:

```py
        config = pulumi.Config()
        slack_channel = SlackChannelConfiguration(
            f"{name}-slack",
            configuration_name="awschatbot",
            iam_role_arn=slack_role.arn,
            slack_channel_id=config.require('SLACK_AWS_CHANNEL_ID'),
            slack_workspace_id=config.require('SLACK_WORKSPACE_ID'),
            opts=opts,
        )
```

Comment: Somehow your code is referencing the `4.33.0` version of the aws classic plugin. Notice how you have aws version `4.33.0` which is different. Can you update the question with your code, and what you did?

Comment: Exactly. I have no clue to why (or how) it understands the version for aws-native should be the same as for aws plugin. I have updated the question with the info you mentioned.

Comment: You haven't added the actual python code and resources you've defined, can you add that?

Comment: I'm trying to use chatbot, which is not included on aws classic. After adding the plugin, I'm just trying to create a `SlackChannelConfigurarion`  resource. Nothing fancy.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this, unfortunately. It's totally unclear how you got into this state, but it's not a normal case.

I'd try clearing your virtualenv, and double check all your imports. Perhaps try using explicit imports to see if that helps